# image gets wrong pixel size in my website on iphone

Tags: iphone, pixel

I've got a iPhone 4S and it has a screen resolution of 640x960px.
My problem is to understand what happens with the pixels when I load my test page in the browser.

My test page has some div's and some images: http://www.macverk.no/test-pixel-iphone.html

I expected that an image 320px wide would cover half of the with when the screenshot I get if 640px wide - but it turns out to be 209px wide!

If it was 160px wide I could better understand it, due to some retina issue... but 209?

A friend told me something about including a viewport setting, but then my iPhone acts like it's a 320x480px screen...

Anoyone who can help?